# Multiplicative Persistence in JS

Tags: javascript, function, integer

I'm working on a coding challenge that wants me to find the multiplicative persistence of any positive integer passed to it.

This is what I have so far.

```
function persistence(num) {
  let persistenceArray = num.toString().split('');
  let counter = 0;
  const multiply = (array) => {
    let sum = 1;
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      sum = sum * parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    return sum.toString();
  }
   while(true){
     if(multiply(persistenceArray).length === 1){
       break;
     }
     else{
       persistenceArray = multiply(persistenceArray).toString().split('');
       counter++;
     }
   }
  return counter;
```

I'm creating a function within the function as it want's done within one function. I've stepped through with console.log's and no luck yet. I'm assuming it's a scope issue but I can't find it.

Example 39 is returning 2 instead of 3 ( 3 * 9 = 27, 2 * 7 = 14, 1 * 4 = 4) so it should return 3)

Comment: Now running into a runtime error and the site force close the code

Answer (score 0):

The counter is always incremented every time you iterate. Your current code does not increment the counter on the final iteration, therefore decreasing the result by 1.

Example: 39 is returning 2 instead of 3 (3 * 9 = 27, 2 * 7 = 14), because on 1 * 4 = 4 it breaks without incrementing the counter.

The while loop should be this:

```js
while(true){
     counter++;
     if(multiply(persistenceArray).length === 1){
       break;
     }
     else{
       persistenceArray = multiply(persistenceArray).toString().split('');
     }
}
```

Also you have a missing curly brace at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but here are a couple of solutions I came up with.

```
/**
 * Using the while loop.
 */

const persistence = (param) => {
  let count = 0;
  let result = param;

  while (result >= 10) {
    result = result
      .toString()
      .split('')
      .reduce((acc, curr) => +acc * +curr, 1);

    count++;
  }

  return count;
};

/**
 * Using recursion.
 */

const persistence = (param) => {
  let count = 0;

  const result = param
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .reduce((acc, curr) => +acc * +curr, 1);

  if (result >= 10) {
    count += persistence(result) + 1;
  }

  return count;
};


console.log('persistence(39)', persistence(39)); // persistence(39) 3
console.log('persistence(999)', persistence(999)); //persistence(999) 4
console.log('persistence(4)', persistence(4)); //persistence(4) 0
console.log('persistence(43)', persistence(43)); //persistence(43) 2
```